# Header Content 3 (tagline area) set to Banner, shortcode for cart added. How to reposition and align

Tags: css, header, position

Folks. Can anyone help me figure out how to center this banner? I have my company's logo on the left side of the screen and would like to use the right side or the tagline area for my cart, as my Main Menu is rather crowded.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: I am very new at this, please let me know from what file, header.css? Just to add more info, I have purchased WP Cart because of the shortcode functionality. I am using the Avada theme. In this theme, there is a field within the Header customization options called "Content 3". One can select it to be a banner, a tagline or empty. I used the tagline option and added the shortcode there. Does that help?

Comment: So you want logo on the left side, banner in the center and cart on the right ? All of them in menu bar (one line)? is that what you want?